# Does the time Evolution operator commute with the both free and interaction Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Consider a quantum system (finite dimensional) which has overall Hamiltonian:

$H_s = H_0 + w(s)H_c$

with $H_0, H_c$ constant in time and traceless and $w(t)$ a, not too badly behaved, function of time.

A) Does the time evolution operator $U(t,s)$ commute with the Hamiltonian at all times? If so, does it commute with both parts of the Hamiltonian separately.

Specifically does: $[H_s, U(t,s) \ H_c \ U(s,t)] = [H_0, U(t,s) \ H_c \  U(s,t)]$

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175594/2451

Comment: I don't think that question is actually so related. It shares some ingredients.